# C# how to add Rows above in Table Panel

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2008, tablelayoutpanel

I am working on arranging the elements of a Form by placing them inside a tablelayoutpanel. Whenever I do an Add row, it goes to the bottom. For the task I have at hand, it would be convenient if this row showed up at the top.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found it, it can be done by doing an insert instead of an add.